# IWindsorContainer RegisterControllers Missing Method AddLifestyle error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I recently updated a 2.5.2 project to 3.2.1 / MVC 4 recompiling the application after a few code fixes, I am getting a Register Controller issue at run-time. Here is the code:

```
    public static void Register(string key, Type interfaceType, Type implementationType)
    {
        //IoC.Container.AddComponent(key, interfaceType, implementationType);
        // IoC.Container.AddComponent is obsolete. Replaced by:
        IoC.Container.Register(Component.For(interfaceType).ImplementedBy(implementationType).Named(key));
    }

    public static void RegisterControllers(params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        //IoC.Container.RegisterControllers(assemblies);

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            IoC.Container.RegisterControllers(assembly.GetExportedTypes());
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterAllFromAssemblies(string baseAssembly, string relatedAssembly)
    {
        // AllTypes is obsolete
        //
        //IoC.Container.Register(AllTypes.
        //    FromAssemblyNamed(baseAssembly).
        //    WithService.
        //    FirstNonGenericCoreInterface(relatedAssembly));

        //Update for Castle-Windor 3.2
        IoC.Container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(baseAssembly)
                .Pick().WithServiceFirstInterface()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

}

The MissingMethod Exception screen shows after execution of                 `IoC.Container.RegisterControllers(assembly.GetExportedTypes());`

`"Method not found: 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer.AddComponentLifeStyle(System.String, System.Type, Castle.Core.LifestyleType)'."`

Pointing me in the right direction would be helpful

Comment: On a side note, have you considerd using the functionality introduced by Windsors `IWindsorInstaller` interface to do this?

Comment: That would be something worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I found this unanswered question meanwhile upgrading a Sharp Architecture based project from SharpArch 1.6 to SharpArch 3.0 and thought a final answer to this might be useful. I got the same problem about

> "Method not found: 'Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer
>   Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer.AddComponentLifeStyle(System.String,
>   System.Type, Castle.Core.LifestyleType)'."

and implemented a solution following the suggestion about IWindsorInstaller from
[Charleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987509/charleh).
Basically, I created an IWindsorInstaller implementation moving there all my needed IoC dependencies registrations

```
public class ComponentsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        AddApplicationServicesTo(container);
        //eventually other services to install
    }

private void AddApplicationServicesTo(IWindsorContainer container)
{

    container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("myAssemblyName1").Pick().WithService.FirstInterface());

    container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("myAssemblyName2").Pick().WithService.FirstInterface());

}
}
```

and called that installer from Global.asax Application_Start with

```
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```